# For loop inside object definition inside Constructor function

Tags: javascript, loops

How do I loop through parameter [array], to create object properties?

As soon as I try to put for loop inside object declaration, it throws a lot of errors.

Is there any other way to do it?

Expected outcome is to loop through parameterArray and based on the length, create i amount of datasets.

```
function Constructor (parameterArray, fill, labels) {
  this.parameterArray = parameterArray;
  this.fill = fill;
  this.labels = labels;

    var object = {
    name: {
        label: labels
    },
    datasets: [
    for (i=0; i<parameterArray.length; i++;) {
        type: parameterArray[i]
      fill: true;
      };
    ]
  }
};

var parameterArray = ["why", "u", "no", "work"];
var fill = true;
var labels = [1,2,3,4];



var helpme = new Constructor (parameterArray, true, labels);
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output when doing `console.log(helpme);`? Please add that to your question.

Comment: From what I see here `parameter` would be undefined here because the argument is `parameterArray`...

Comment: my fault, let me fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.map` to map each entry in the array to another one (I omitted `parameter` as it seems `undefined`) :

```js
function Constructor (parameterArray, fill, labels) {
  this.fill = fill;
  this.labels = labels;

  this.dataset = {
    name: {
      label: labels
    },
    datasets: parameterArray.map(type => ({
      type, fill: true
    }))
  }
};

var parameterArray = ["why", "u", "no", "work"];
var fill = true;
var labels = [1,2,3,4];



var helpme = new Constructor (parameterArray, true, labels); 

console.log('De nada', helpme)
```

Comment: thanks. Why would it not work if the this.dataset had an array of objects? Such as `this.dataset = [{datasets: parameterArray.map <and so on>}]`